# Windows 10 update error: BITS Service "The requested service has already been started"

Tags: windows, windows-update, updates

Running windows 10 pro 64 bit.

Keep getting this error all of a sudden:

```
There were problems downloading some updates, but we'll try again later. 
If you keep seeing this, try searching the web or contacting support for help. 
This error code might help: (0x80070001)
```

I have run the trouble shooter, also followed steps based on the error on this site https://windowsreport.com/how-to-fix-the-net-helpmsg-2182-error/ and still will not work.

```
Detection details 
Expand 

Informational
IsPostback_RC_PendingUpdates 
IsPostback: False 
 
Informational
Service Status 
Problem with BITS service : The requested service has already been started. 
System.Management.Automation.RemoteException M
ore help is available by typing NET HELPMSG 2182.
System.Management.Automation.RemoteException 



Background Intelligent Transfer Service 
Find and fix problems that may prevent background downloads from working 
Package Version: 3.5 
Publisher: Microsoft Windows 
Windows Network Diagnostics 
Detects problems with network connectivity. 
Package Version: 4.0 
Publisher: Microsoft Windows 
Windows Update 
Resolve problems that prevent you from updating Windows. 
Package Version: 9.3 
Publisher: Microsoft Windows 
Windows Update 
Resolve problems that prevent you from updating Windows. 
Package Version: 9.2 
Publisher: Microsoft Corporation 

Print
Windows Update Publisher details 

Potential issues that were checked 
Some security settings are missing or have been changed
Some security settings are missing or have been changed 
Issue not present  
Check for missing or corrupt files
Check for missing or corrupt files 
Issue not present  
Service registration is missing or corrupt
Service registration is missing or corrupt 
Issue not present  
Check for Windows Update issues
Check for Windows Update issues
Detects issues related to Windows Update. I
ssue not present  

Potential issues that were checked 
Detection details 

 Some security settings are missing or have been changed Issue not present  
 
 
 Check for missing or corrupt files 
Issue not present  
 
 
 Service registration is missing or corrupt 
Issue not present  
 
 
 Check for Windows Update issues 
Issue not present  
 
Detects issues related to Windows Update.
```

Comment: One common set of repair steps for this is DISM / SFC  ......  1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.
(2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup
(3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth
(4) SFC /SCANNOW
(5) Restart when all the above is complete and test.

Comment: @john thank you for the reply, did all the steps scan turned out fine no issues restart however still same error when trying to update.

Comment: Have you restarted the PC?

Answer (score 0):

A common initial answer to your question is to run the DISM, SFC sequence of steps.

You did so and said the steps ran fine but the update error remains.

So now do a Windows 10 Repair install.

Go to the Media Creation Link:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Windows 10 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade Button) and select Run.

There are 3 ways to proceed, according to the severity of the error.

> (1) Keep Everything: Best if it works and your computer comes back
> just the way you had set it up except repaired.  Always have a backup,
> but generally nothing will be lost.
>
> (2) Keep Data: Necessary if the operating system damage is extensive.
> Keeps the User Profile and makes software install quite easy. Always
> have a backup, but data is not usually lost.
>
> (3) Keep Nothing: Deletes the User Profile and all else and is
> essentially a fresh install.  Be certain you have backed up all your
> data. "Keep Nothing" is necessary if the User Profile is damaged,
> because broken User Profiles cannot be repaired and it is generally
> easier to back up and start over if the User Profile is damaged. It
> depends on the precise situation.

Start with Keep Everything and see if that works. If not try the second method of Keep Data. Then if all the above fails, back up and try the third method (Keep Nothing).